# How to edit files directly on server with GVim when ssh is mounted from Dolphin?

Tags: remote, dolphin, gvim

I would like to use GVim to edit external files that are accessed through Dolphin.

1. I have an external server with files to be modified
2. I access the server using SSH using Dolphin's built-in module
3. I right click on a file and edit it with GVim
4. GVim open a copy of the file stored in `/var/tmp/kdecache-<user>/krun/4553434_0_.<filename>`

If I modify the file **I have to close GVim** to have a dialog box asking me to send the file to the server.

So, I'm not able to make multiple changes without closing/re-opening my files and this is not possible for work.

Is there a solution to simple edit my files on servers using SSH or FTP with GVim?

Comment: Is the use of GVim really a requirement? It doesn't integrate that well with KDE applications. Please consider Kate, that features perfect integration with the KDE set of applications. Lots of plugins available and I've seen plugins to provide vi-like input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better answer but if you want to use gvim to edit a file remotely though Dolphin you may want to look at mounting the remote location with sshfs.

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04. For me to get `sshfs` working I needed the following steps:

```
sudo apt install sshfs # (it was already installed so  I could have skipped this step)

sudo groupadd  fuse # the group did not exist for me

sudo usermod -a -G fuse phall
```

Now I needed to logout/log back in (I rebooted) before it would register my user name belonging to the new group. Then I could run sshfs without being root:

```
sshfs user@remote:/my/remote/path /local/mount/path
```